# Write a basis for a subset of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that 
$W = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    3s - 2t \\
    s + 2t \\  
    2s + 3t \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $s$ and $t$ are real numbers is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, I need to write a basis of $W$ and state the dimension of $W$.

I believe that the basis is the set 
$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
    3\\
    1\\  
    2\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ , 
$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -2\\
    2\\  
    3\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$
 since they both contain pivot positions. I am not sure if this is correct though. Also I do not know how to find the dimensino of $W$.

Comment: Does this help?  $$\begin{bmatrix}
    3s - 2t \\
    s + 2t \\  
    2s + 3t \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = s\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$ So $W$ is the set of linear combinations of $\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I have already established that from a previous part of the question

Comment: OK.  Well this clearly shows that those two vectors form a *spanning set* for $W$.  So what's the relationship between a spanning set and a basis?

Comment: linear independence ?

Comment: That is not a full sentence (or idea) ... but yes, it involves linear independence.

Answer (score 0):

If you show ⎢312⎤⎦⎥[312]  , ⎡⎣⎢−223⎤⎦⎥ are linearly independent then they form a basis for W as they span W which would mean the dimension is 2.

Comment: they are linearly independent . correct?

Comment: yes it can be shown easily